# How to ues "dumpsys batterystats" to get a app's Power Consumption‘s Percentage

Tags: adb, battery, dumpsys

I want to know how can i get the information of the percentage of a app's use of battery

Comment: I've also tried to figure it out. It has "Time on battery" and "Total run time" in case you give the command the exact package name of the app, but if you compare it to the global time, it's still not the same percentage as of the battery management screen of Android. I just don't get how it works...